# Zabbix Triggers iregex expression validation

Tags: zabbix

I am a beginner in zabbix agent.I would like to know if the below trigger is  syntactically correct? If yes then how do I know if the trigger is fired ?
I am not able to receive email notifications.Kindly help me .

```
{MDMCenter:eventlog[761848].iregexp("Job.Execute() failed. (ex.Message =  System.Exception: Exception: Failed in Batch: [1] of \[[0-9]*\] ---> System.Exception: Exception: Failed in Batch: [1] of \[[0-9]*\]] ---> System.IO.IOException: The network name cannot be found.")}
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression as you have it here seems to be invalid - looks like you have accidentally added some example value inside the function parameters.

You can look for the trigger firing on the dashboard or in the Monitoring -> Triggers page.

In general, before even looking at triggers, verify that data is coming in and that the values match your expectations. If some trigger still does not seem to work, always provide exact trigger expression and a few example values, as well as all the things you have checked (server being running, item values being recent and so on).

Comment: Hi thanks for the information.I wrote around 25 triggers  but they are not getting fired. Is it possible to guide me? Inbuilt zabbix triggers are working fine. But he one's I have written are not. Thanks in advance

Comment: That is not a specific question that can be answered - but I have added some additional hints on how to improve the question and approach debugging in general.

Comment: Thanks for the Info. So where do i find them? Could you share it?

Comment: I am not sure what is "them" you are looking for. The hints have been included in my answer.